# how to instantiate Map<String, TreeMap<Integer, Integer> >?

Tags: java, dictionary, constructor

I am wondering how to instantiate Map < String, TreeMap < Integer, Integer > >, using Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the implementation classes of the `Map` Interface e.g. `HashMap` or `TreeMap` as below:

```
    Map < String, TreeMap < Integer, Integer > > myMap = 
                          new HashMap< String, TreeMap < Integer, Integer > >();
```

or

```
    Map < String, TreeMap < Integer, Integer > > myMap = 
                          new TreeMap< String, TreeMap < Integer, Integer > >();
```

To add the values:

```
    //Instantiate TreeMap element as below  
    TreeMap< Integer, Integer > elemMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();

    //add elements to tree map
    elemMap.put(1, 100);

    //put the tree map in the map
    myMap.put("firstElem", elemMap);
```

Comment: @Jack: If you are looking for more inputs. If the answer is helpful, then accept it.